# getting my gmail in emacs

Tags: emacs, gmail, gnus

I wish to use emacs as my email client. Currently, I have a gmail account and I found this link which supposedly will get your gmail into emacs via **gnus**:

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GnusGmail#toc1

I created the files `.gnus` and `.authinfo` in the `/usr/share/emacs24.3/etc/gnus/` directory. Then I copied and pasted the information from the website into those files and changed the email and password fields according to the instructions.

Then I ran `M-x gnus` without success... It freezes with an ascii art picture of the gnu goat. If I try to quit with `C-g` I get the following message:

```
nntp (news) open error: ''.  Continue? (y or n)
```

This does not help either...

1. What else can I do to get gmail to work through emacs?
2. All suggestions are welcome, I do not really know what else to do...

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

The .gnus and .authinfo files need to be in your home directory.

Comment: As soon as I moved both of those files, it worked (thanks!). However, I changed the email address and now it will not work even if I change it back to the original address...

Comment: That does not make any sense to me... All I did was change the contents of the `.gnus` and `.authoinfo` files...

Answer (score 0):

The following link fixed me additional problems:

http://www.mostlymaths.net/2010/12/emacs-30-day-challenge-using-gnus-to.html